# Ruby "once" method no longer works after upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0p648

Tags: ruby

I have some expensive subs that, if called multiple times, can cause the process running to take an eternity to complete.

To stop them from being called repeatedly a `Once` module was created similar to the one in date.rb:

```
module Once
  # modify a method to run only once
  def once(*ids) # :nodoc:
    ids.each do |id|
      module_eval <<-"end;"
                alias_method :__#{id.to_i}__, :#{id.to_s}
                private :__#{id.to_i}__
                def #{id.to_s}(*args, &block)
                    (@__#{id.to_i}__ ||= [__#{id.to_i}__(*args, &block)])[0]
                end
      end;
    end
  end

end
```

Which was used like this:

```
def expensive_function
    blah, blah
end
once :expensive_function
```

This worked fine in Ruby 1.8.6 but now, after I upgraded to Ruby 2.0.0p648, I get the following error:

```
:in `block in once': undefined method `to_i' for :log_level_from_env:Symbol (NoMethodError)
```

This error is referencing the line number containing `alias_method`.

What modifications are needed to correct this module so it will work as needed with my current Ruby version?

Comment: This sounds like a good case for memoizing.

Comment: The method `Symbol#to_i` was removed in Ruby 1.9.1. I think you can use [`Object#object_id`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id) instead.

Comment: What about using [Memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist)?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note that since ruby 2.0 `def method_name; end` returns `:method_name` symbol so you can write in such a way

```
once def method_name
  ...
end
```

Here is the working snippet of the same working in ruby 2.3.3

```
module Once
  # modify a method to run only once
  def once(*method_names) # :nodoc:
    method_names.each do |method_name|
      module_eval <<~RUBY
        alias_method :__#{method_name.to_s}__, :#{method_name.to_s}

        private :__#{method_name.to_s}__

        def #{method_name.to_s}(*args, &block)
          (@__#{method_name.to_s}__ ||= [__#{method_name.to_s}__(*args, &block)])[0]
        end
      RUBY
    end
  end
end

class FooBar
  extend Once

  once def test
    puts 'FooBar'
  end
end

foo_bar = FooBar.new
100.times do
  foo_bar.test
end
```

**P. S.**

Also there is a nice gem which is created for same purposes [memoizer](https://github.com/wegowise/memoizer), maybe you find it usefull